# Can't figure out which dimens.xml used by different devices

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm using different `dimens.xml` to allow my app to support different screen resolution. 

The problem is that it looks like dimension are missing for `Nexus S` and `Nexus One` and it also looks like if `Nexus 7` (both version) and `Nexus 9` are sharing the same `dimens.xml` file.

Here's the list of my `dimens.xml` files (if there're some "useless" file please tell me, I will remove them).

[Dimens.xml files pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjTTW.png)

Here's another pic showing you the result on different screen res.

[Results on different resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afN0Y.png)

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using the identifier sw (smallest width). I think that will be much easier to maintain.

Edit:
Just change w600 to sw600. This way only screens with minimum width of 600 dp will use those dimensions. check this link stackoverflow.com/a/32685049/4567228

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  What are the difference between sw and w?  How should I use sw instead of w?